Как сделать доп. окошко, независимое от самой игры? (Unity)
Я делаю счётчик дней на Unity. Есть основное окно с кнопками и отображением прожитых дней, но данное окно большое (плюс много занимают кнопки управления состоянием окна).
Я хочу сделать доп. маленькое окно, которое будет отображать дни, но находиться за пределами основного окна проекта (например, в углу другой игры).
Можно ли как-то реализовать данную идею? В идеале чтобы окно можно было передвигать и открывать/закрывать через кнопку на главной панели.
Пробовал через GUI.window, но там окно показывается чисто в пределах программы.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/MultiDisplay.html оно?

@aepot Вроде как MultiDisplay не позволяет создать двигающееся окно + должен быть второй монитор. Когда то я давно тоже искал решение для подобной задачи, и ничего не нашёл, вроде как это вообще не возможно с использованием только внутренних unity штуках. Мб создавать новое окно через OpenTK или любую другую подобную либу...

Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?
